# F2PY cannot see module-scope variables

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, fortran90, f2py

Sorry about being new to both Fortran 90 and f2py.

I am using Windows 64 bit, Python 3.4 64 bit, gfortran. Numpy version is 1.9.1, and I
commented the "raise NotImplementedError("Only MS compiler supported
with gfortran on win64")" in the gnu.py, as instructed on this link:
http://scientificcomputingco.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/f2py-on-64bit-windows-python27.html

I have a module in fortran, written as follows, with a module-scope variable `dp`:

```
! testf2py.f90
module testf2py
    implicit none
    private
    public dp, i1
    integer, parameter :: dp=kind(0.d0)
contains
    real(dp) function i1(m)
        real(dp), intent(in) :: m(3, 3)
        i1 = m(1, 1) + m(2, 2) + m(3, 3)
        return
    end function i1
end module testf2py
```

Then, if I run `f2py -c testf2py.f90 -m testf2py`

It would report an error, stating that dp was not declared.

If I copy the module-scope to the function-scope, it would work.

```
! testf2py.f90
module testf2py
    implicit none
    private
    public i1
    integer, parameter :: dp=kind(0.d0)
contains
    real(dp) function i1(m)
        integer, parameter :: dp=kind(0.d0)
        real(dp), intent(in) :: m(3, 3)
        i1 = m(1, 1) + m(2, 2) + m(3, 3)
        return
    end function i1
end module testf2py
```

However, this does not look like the best coding practice though, as
it is pretty "wet".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a work-around, in which `dp` is moved to a `types` module, and the `use types` statement is added to the function `i1`.

```
! testf2py.f90

module types
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp=kind(0.d0)
end module types

module testf2py
    implicit none
    private
    public i1
contains
    real(dp) function i1(m)
        use types
        real(dp), intent(in) :: m(3, 3)
        i1 = m(1, 1) + m(2, 2) + m(3, 3)
        return
    end function i1
end module testf2py
```

In action:

```
In [6]: import numpy as np

In [7]: m = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]])

In [8]: import testf2py

In [9]: testf2py.testf2py.i1(m)
Out[9]: 150.0
```

The change is similar to the third option that I described in this answer: [f2py: Specifying real precision in fortran when interfacing with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523524/f2py-specifying-real-precision-in-fortran-when-interfacing-with-python/12524403#12524403)

Comment: Nice.  I approve (and miss my f2py fortran-python days ... :-/).

Comment: @Warren Thank you for your response! And sorry about the late response. I also got the email from the mailing list, but figured that a discussion here would probably be accessible to more people. I do have a question, that I do not understand why this is happening. I do understand that f2py does not take where `kind=kind(0.d0)` because a function call of `kind()` is used. My questions are:

Comment: 1) if we compile the module `types` first, why would `dp` be OK in this way? Is it because it is compiled first so it no longer is a function call? 2) Why would it fail if the `use  types, only : dp` statement was at the module level? And why would it work if it is placed at the function level?

Comment: All good questions; I wish I had the answers.   Maybe @mgilson can revive his f2py fortran-python skills and provide some wisdom. :-)

Comment: @ShawnWang -- Mostly I'm guessing that this is a result of the f2py parser not being a full language parser.  Out of curiosity, what happens if you move the "integer, parameter" declaration _above_ the public dp statement in your original post?

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for your answer! And sorry for the late response! I just tried that, and it remained the same - dp was not found. Well, I guess then I have to switched to a "f2py" coding style then :) I use to think that I can remain my old f90 coding style, where I only import module scope variables at module level...