# Why does a Fortran function compiled with f2py return zero when I change the name of the result variable?

Tags: fortran, f2py

When I call the following function, it returns `1` as expected:

```
integer function my_func() result(myresult)
    myresult = 1
end function my_func
```

But when I modify the name of the return value to start with the letter "r" then the function returns `0`.

```
integer function my_func() result(rresult)
    rresult = 1
end function my_func
```

What is causing this? My first thought was that it related to implicit typing, but the function is within a module that specifies `implicit none`.

Here is the complete module

```
module my_mod
implicit none

contains

integer function my_func() result(myresult)
    myresult = 1
end function my_func

end module my_mod
```

I am using Fortran 90 and compiling with gfortran.

**EDIT**

Here is a complete program to demonstrate the problem

Makefile:

```
.PHONY: pytest clean

CYTHON_LIB = fortran_mods.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
FFLAGS += -fdefault-real-8

pytest: $(CYTHON_LIB)
        ./tests.py

$(CYTHON_LIB): my_mod.F90
        f2py -c -m fortran_mods my_mod.F90 --f90flags="$(FFLAGS)"

clean:
        rm *.so
```

my_mod.F90:

```
module my_mod
implicit none

contains

!********************************************************

integer function my_func_without_r() result(myresult)
    myresult = 1
end function

integer function my_func_with_r() result(rresult)
    rresult = 1
end function

end module my_mod
```

tests.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fortran_mods
from fortran_mods import *

print("with r:", my_mod.my_func_with_r())
print("without r:", my_mod.my_func_without_r())
```

The output when `make pytest` is run and `FFLAGS += -fdefault-real-8` is included in the Makefile is

```
with r: 0.0
without r: 1
```

and otherwise is

```
with r: 1.0
without r: 1
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce this. Can you show a complete program (or programs) that show the problem, tell us how you are compiling it, and what version of gfortran you are using.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not able to reproduce it with pure Fortran either. I'm using f2py to call the functions from Python, so perhaps that is where the problem lies. I'll post an example in a bit.

Comment: @IanBush, I've added an program that exhibits the problem

Comment: Using -fdefault-real-8 is a really stupid idea.

Comment: Well I don't really know python, but looking at the output it looks as though python thinks my_func_with_r returns some kind of real, as it prints a number with a decimal point, while it thinks my_func_without_r returns an integer, as there is no decimal point. This is almost certainly the cause of your problem, but I don't know enough about python and f2py to say why. And I also have to second evets comment - using compiler flags to change default data types to something different is just asking for a world of pain due to the subtle side effects that invariably occur.

Comment: @evets, why is `-fdefault-real-8` a bad idea?

Comment: -fdefault-real-8 is a bad idea because it may not do what you think it does.  It violates Fortran's association rules, and screws up `equivalence`, `common`, argument passing and a few other things.  Don't use it.  It is better to copy the code to a new file, and properly port it from `REAL` to `DOUBLE PRECISION`.  Before you or anyone else questions my understanding of -default-real-8, look up its history!

Comment: I wasn't questioning your understanding, I was just looking for an explanation so **I** would understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is definitely with how F2PY wraps the Fortran functions, not the Fortran code itself.

To gain a bit more insight into how F2PY wraps a function (especially if things don't work out as expected), it always helps to split the process into parts (see [The smart way](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/getting-started.html#the-smart-way)). So first create a *signature file* allowing you to see how F2PY interpreted your code. For your particular example, run:

```
f2py -m fortran_mods -h my_mod.pyf my_mod.F90
```

This will produce a signature file `my_mod.pyf` looking something like this:

```
python module fortran_mods ! in 
    interface  ! in :fortran_mods
        module my_mod ! in :fortran_mods:my_mod.F90
            function my_func_without_r() result (myresult) ! in :fortran_mods:my_mod.F90:my_mod
                integer :: myresult
            end function my_func_without_r
            function my_func_with_r() result (rresult) ! in :fortran_mods:my_mod.F90:my_mod
                real :: rresult
            end function my_func_with_r
        end module my_mod
    end interface 
end python module fortran_mods
```

Clearly F2PY has misidentified `my_func_with_r`'s result variable `rresult` as `real`. You could simply replace the `real :: rresult` with the intended `integer :: rresult` in `my_mod.pyf`, take the next/second step of F2PY wrapping, and compile using the corrected signature file:

```
f2py -c my_mod.pyf my_mod.F90
```

Your python script should now give the expected output.

This approach of modifying the signature file may not be desired if you have many functions to wrap. What may be causing difficulty for F2PY is that your function definitions use result variables, without type definitions for them appearing in the body of the function (i.e. a F2PY problem, not a Fortran problem). If you change your function definitions to e.g.:

```
function my_func_with_r() result(rresult)
    integer :: rresult
    rresult = 1
end function
```

or

```
integer function my_func_with_r()
    my_func_with_r = 1
end function
```

you can do the F2PY wrapping in one step as you did originally, and should still get the correct output.

Finally, I'll add another vote to the concerns raised in the comments: using `-fdefault-real-8` when wrapping functions with F2PY is asking for trouble. To [make a Fortran procedure callable from Python](https://dx.doi.org/10.1504/IJCSE.2009.029165), F2PY creates:

> a Python C/API extension module (called as wrapper module) that
>   implements a Python extension function (written in C, called as
>   wrapper function) which in turn calls the given Fortran procedure.

This whole process is based on how F2PY interprets data types from your Fortran source code - if source code is compiled with compiler flags that change the declared data types, things are bound to end up broken (directly similar to the `real`/`integer` mismatch your original question is about). The data types for your variables and functions should therefore be explicitly set in the Fortran code itself, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/856243/3967096) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3170239/3967096) about Fortran's `kind` parameter in general, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12524403/3967096) related to F2PY in particular.

Comment: Thank you, that was extremely helpful. What is the danger of using `-fdefault-real-8` and what would be the better way to specify the floating point percision?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain the dangers of using `-fdefault-real-8` and added links to other questions/answers explaining how to correctly define floating point precision in your Fortran code.